# How can use multi if for one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble using if condition in PHP
only Two of `if(s)` are working, Here is the code block in PHP

```
if($_POST) {
    if(($_POST['type'] == '0') && ($_POST['priceminrahn'] != '') && ($_POST["priceminej"] != '') && ($_POST["mahale"] != '0')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_mahaleh='$mahal' AND  orders_polpish between '$priceminrahn' AND '$pricemaxrahn' AND orders_ejarehbaha between '$priceminej' AND '$pricemaxej' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if(($_POST['type'] == '0') && ($_POST['priceminrahn'] != '')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_polpish between '$priceminrahn' AND '$pricemaxrahn' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if(($_POST['type'] == '0') && ($_POST['priceminrahn'] != '') && ($_POST["priceminej"] != '')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND  orders_polpish between '$priceminrahn' AND '$pricemaxrahn' AND orders_ejarehbaha between '$priceminej' AND '$pricemaxej' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if(($_POST['type'] == '0') && ($_POST["mahale"] != '')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_mahaleh='$mahal' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if(($_POST['type'] == '0') && ($_POST["state"] != '') && ($_POST["mahale"] == '0')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_ostan='$ostan' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
} else {
    $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1'";
}
```

Only two of the if work

I want any of the conditions to be executed

I want to filter data by input

Comment: why extra brackets `(`  and `)` in condition

Comment: why not use `elseif` ?

Comment: Please provide sample inputs, current result/output, and expected/desired result/output.

Comment: What do you mean, only two work? It's only going into two of the if blocks, or only two queries work while the rest fail? What about it "doesn't work"? Please provide more information as well as any troubleshooting steps you might have taken.

Comment: Your if statements aren't mutually exclusive. This means that more than one of them can be true at any time. E.g. if type is '1' and priceminrahn is '10' and priceminej is '15', then both the second and third if conditions will be true, and the `$sql` variable will be overwritten. You need to be more precise with your if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST['type'] == '0'){
    if(($_POST['priceminrahn'] != '') && ($_POST["priceminej"] != '') && ($_POST["mahale"] != '0')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_mahaleh='$mahal' AND  orders_polpish between '$priceminrahn' AND '$pricemaxrahn' AND orders_ejarehbaha between '$priceminej' AND '$pricemaxej' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if(($_POST["state"] != '') && ($_POST["mahale"] == '0')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_ostan='$ostan' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if(($_POST['priceminrahn'] != '') && ($_POST["priceminej"] != '')) {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND  orders_polpish between '$priceminrahn' AND '$pricemaxrahn' AND orders_ejarehbaha between '$priceminej' AND '$pricemaxej' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if($_POST["mahale"] != ''){
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_mahaleh='$mahal' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    if($_POST['priceminrahn'] != '') {
        $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1' AND orders_polpish between '$priceminrahn' AND '$pricemaxrahn' AND orders_subject='1'";
    }
    }
} else {
    $sql = "select * from orders JOIN city ON orders.orders_mahaleh = city.id where orders_show='1'";
}
```